# What command to analyze the traffic in Freeswitch

Tags: asterisk

What is the command in freeswitch to analyse the trafic, our vendor don't want to inform what command is it, they share the screenshot like below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How this freeswitch question is related to asterisk?

Answer (score 1):

The command you show is sngrep. Available on every Linux distro. Another external command you can use is tcpdump(simpler one).

You also can enable sip trace on Sofia

```
fscli
sofia loglevel all 9
sofia global siptrace on
```

https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/Troubleshooting-Debugging/#enabling-sip-tracing

https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/Configuration/Sofia-SIP-Stack/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using:

```
sngrep -cr
```